# Iterator for AVL Tree with Removal and Insertion (C++ implementation)

Tags: c++, performance, iteration, traversal, avl-tree

I have implemented a template based AVL tree, and I'm struggling to implement an in-order iterator that comes with each tree that is robust with insertion and removal of elements. *I'll include only a bit of the code given its length* - please let me know if more is necessary.

**Node Based Code Below**

The nodes hold a left and right child pointer and a reference to the occupancy of the tree.

```
    T * data;
    AVLNode<T> * left; 
    AVLNode<T> * right; 
    int height; 
    int balance; 
    int & occupancy;
```

Insertion and removal occurs recursively, with a reference to the pointer from the parent to "this" passed as a parameter in either case. Their implementation is fairly standard as far as binary search trees go. Removal of nodes with two children occurs through replacing the data of the node to be removed with the successor node data, and deleting the successor node.

```
    int insert(T * element, AVLNode<T> * &pfp, int &occupancy); 
    int remove(T & element, AVLNode<T> * &pfp)
```

Left and right rotations make use of the reference to the pointer from the parent node.

```
     void leftRotation(AVLNode<T> * &pfp) { 
        pfp = right; 
        right = right->left; 
        pfp->left = this; 
     }
     void rightRotation(AVLNode<T> * &pfp) { 
        pfp = left; 
        left = left->right; 
        pfp->right = this; 
     }
```

**Iterator Based Code Below**

The iterator is a part of the tree, and the methods are called through the reference or pointer to the tree. For example, given a MyTestObject class with a printMyTestObject method, one might write:

```
    TreeAVL<MyTestObject> myTree;  
    myTree.iteratorBegin(); 
    while (myTree.iteratorHasNext()) { 
        (myTree.iteratorNext())->printMyTestObject(&cout);
    }
```

The iterator has the following methods.

```
    void iteratorBegin(); 
    T * iteratorNext(); 
    int iteratorHasNext();
```

While I initially used std::stack, I felt that dequeue which it's implemented over has limited functionality. I made my own singly linked list, which accepts and handles void * as its data fields. The following Node methods are called by the AVL Tree's iteratorBegin() and  iteratorNext() on its root Node.

```
    void begin(List * const iteratorList) { 
        AVLNode<T> * targetNode = this; 
        while (targetNode) { 
            iteratorList->push(targetNode); 
            targetNode = targetNode->left; 
        }
    }

    T * next(List * const iteratorList) const { 
        AVLNode<T> * returnNode = (AVLNode<T> *)iteratorList->pop(); 
        AVLNode<T> * loadNode = returnNode->right;  

        while (loadNode) { 
            iteratorList->push(loadNode); 
            loadNode = loadNode->left; 
        }
        return returnNode->data; 
    }
```

This works all fine and dandy, using O(log(n)) memory and operating in an average of O(1) time for successive iterations. It allows me to iterate over the entire tree by calling iteratorBegin(), iteratorHasNext(), and iteratorNext(), or incrementally by calling the latter two methods.

**The Problem**

Removal and insertion of elements may reorganize the tree along the stack path used to get to the top node of the iterator list. This means that the stack path held in the list will be incorrect. How could I implement the iterator to efficiently account for removal and insertion of tree elements, aside from completely repopulating the list? This would be fairly expensive of an operation. I've searched far and wide on the internet, but I can't find a concrete, working implementation, especially without parent pointers.

For an example of the insertion problem:

```
      - g -                            - g -
     /     \                          /      \
    e       i                        c        i 
   / \     / \    == insert d ==>   / \      /  \
  b   f   h   j                    b   e    h    j
 / \                              /   / \
a   c                            a   d   f
```

The list initially holds "a -> b -> e -> g". Let's say we call iteratorNext(). The list now holds "b -> e -> g". After insertion of d, the current iterator will spit out *b e f g h i j*, skipping c and d completely.

The problem with removal is trivially apparent.

Comment: The simple options are either to just assert that mutating the tree invalidates iterators, or to add parent pointers to your node (and fix them up during rebalancing) so that you don't need a separate stack. If you _must_ use a separate (per-iterator?) structure, you'll need to do something fancy to synchronise it with the main tree.

Comment: Oh, and since you're writing C++, I'd strongly recommend using standard iterator syntax rather than this C-style begin/hasNext/next